# dateFromString returning nil for 12 hour format irrespective of setting locale to "en_US_POSIX"

Tags: ios, swift3

trying to get the date from string in a particular date format but the dateFormatter.dateFrom(String) is returning nil. The device has 12 hour format. It works when it is changed to 24 hour format.I have even set the locale to en_US_POSIX but still not working.Can somebody please help me with the issue.

Comment: What is the particular date format? What is the date string?

Comment: The actual date is in format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +SSSS" which is to be converted into "EEEE,MMM dd yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code:

```
let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter1.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale
dateFormatter1.dateStyle = .none
dateFormatter1.timeStyle = .short
timeFromText.text = dateFormatter1.string(from: fromTimePicker.date)
```